# BMP image code for PHP

Tags: php

I have a system where you upload an image from folder and it'll automatically appear on a certain page after compressed. It works fine for PNG, GIF & JPG but I've been trying to add BMP support but it gives me error. I couldn't find many other alternatives for BNP codes to be used, any suggestions?

This is how the important parts looks like:

```
     $dsg_allowed_extensions = array();
    if ( ! isset($dsg_allow_gif) || $dsg_allow_gif == TRUE ) {
      array_push($dsg_allowed_extensions, 'gif');
    }
    if ( ! isset($dsg_allow_bmp) || $dsg_allow_bmp == TRUE ) {
      array_push($dsg_allowed_extensions, 'bmp');
    }
    if ( ! isset($dsg_allow_jpg) || $dsg_allow_jpg == TRUE ) {
      array_push($dsg_allowed_extensions, 'jpg');
      array_push($dsg_allowed_extensions, 'jpeg');
    }
    if ( ! isset($dsg_allow_png) || $dsg_allow_png == TRUE ) {
      array_push($dsg_allowed_extensions, 'png');
    }


    function dsgLoadImage($image) {
      switch ($image['type']) {
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: return imagecreatefromjpeg( $image['fullpath'] );
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:  return imagecreatefromgif( $image['fullpath'] );
        case IMAGETYPE_BMP:  return imagecreatefrombmp( $image['fullpath'] );
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:  return imagecreatefrompng( $image['fullpath'] );

case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      if (! @imagejpeg($new_image, $destination_path, $compression) ) {
        throw new Exception ("Writing to file failed.");
      }
      break;
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        if (! @imagegif($new_image, $destination_path) ) {
          throw new Exception ("Writing to file failed.");
        }
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
      if (! @imagepng($new_image, $destination_path) ) {
        throw new Exception ("Writing to file failed.");
      }
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
      if (! @imagebmp($new_image, $destination_path) ) {
        throw new Exception ("Writing to file failed.");
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also, where does `imagecreatefrom...` come from?

Comment: The error I'm getting is that the BMP filetype isn't supported. Also the imagecreate comes from creating a thumb for the gallery. (this is not the entire source, I only took the pieces with the filetypes because I'm uncertain the BMP works for this.)

Comment: I mean, what library is that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I didn't write this from scratch, I've only customized it a little. Should I send you the full source?

Comment: uh... do I understand correctly we don't have enough information to fix that unless we are willing to dig through an entire application?

Comment: Unfortunately. :( I'll try look for an alternative solution.   Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the function imagecreatefrombmp() does not exist in PHP, as the GD2 library does not support BMP formatted files. There's an imagecreatefromwbmp() (note the 'w') that works for WBMP files; not what you need. Someone from the Bytes community wrote a naive replacement for the missing function (doesn't cover all cases). See [his post](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/4399-imagecreatefrombmp).

**Update**

The function `imagecreatefrombmp()` is [available](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefrombmp) since PHP 7